# Facebook SessionState always not FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded

Tags: objective-c, facebook

I use the latest Facebook SDK (3.1.1).

I wrote a function in my `AppDelegate` that checks the current session and creates or opens a session according to the state.

The second conditions always return `NO` and go to show login screen.

I don't understand way.

AppDelegate method:

```
if (facebook.isOpen == NO)
{
   facebook = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permission];

    if (facebook.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded)
    {
        [facebook openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState status,NSError *error)
        {
            // load user details
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        // show login screen
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property access token in the FbSession class.

Use that string in order to check the login status.

If you are getting null in that string it means your session is expired but if you are getting some value in that is means you are still login in the app and you can do what ever you want.

Regards

Abhishek Goyal

Comment: The facebook.accessToken always nil too.

Comment: can you share the code how you are getting the Facebook access token?

Comment: I found the problem - I tried to init session twice with different permissions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if the session state equal to FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded it means that there is a cached accessToken, a call to open* will result in an open session, without UX or app-switching

```
-(BOOL)validFBSessionExists{
        if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen){
            NSLog(@"Facebook accessToken:%@",FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.accessToken);
            return YES;
        }
        else if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded)
        {
            // Cached token exist, Session needs to be re-opened
            [FBSession.activeSession openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent completionHandler:nil];
            return YES;
        }
        return NO;
}
```